# Url rewriting using .htaccess.What to do?

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

Sorry for poor title.
I am now using

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Its works fine when using `localhost/home`
But my problem is when typing `localhost/home.php` it also works.I want to redirect when typing `localhost/home.php` to an error page that the requested page does not exist.

How could i do it with .htaccess or should i use php to redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you request the URL with the '.php' extension, none of your .htaccess conditions are met, so the server (Apache) just serves the request normally. That's why it works.

The easiest in my opinion is to add another rule *before* the previous one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.php$ # if it ends in .php
# note we're using REQUEST_URI above to only match when
# the URI ends in .php, not the requested file,
# otherwise we would have a endless loop!
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /error_page.php # note the leading slash
```

Add the `[R]` option to the `RedirectRule` if you want the browser to redirect (and I think you need to add a full path), eg:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /path/error_page.php [R]
```

Comment: I had a redirect loop when using RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://localhost/error [R]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Comment: don't put `localhost` (the hostname) in the rewrite, just start it with `/`.

Comment: if that still doesn't work, try adding the `L` option as well (i.e. `[R,L]`) but I doubt it would need that

Comment: oh oops, I see the problem, give me a minute

Comment: had to try it to fix it. updated the answer. changed `REQUEST_FILENAME` to `REQUEST_URI` in first condition, and added leading slash to `RewriteRule`

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is appending ".php" to REQUEST_FILENAME if it isn't a directory, and if adding ".php" to it results in an existing page. When you type `localhost/home.php` the rewrite doesn't fire, because it won't find `localhost/home.php.php`. So for this second scenario, the rewrite is completely irrelevant. You probably need to check whether you have your normal handling for 404 situations set up correctly. For example, do you have an [ErrorDocument](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument) directive configured? Then you might consider removing the `-f` condition and letting it redirect to `home.php.php` which would of course fail.